# Vim search and replace, adding a constant

Tags: regex, vim, data-manipulation

I know this is a long shot, but I have a huge text file and I need to add a given number to other numbers matching some criteria.

Eg.

```
identifying text 1.1200
identifying text 1.1400
```

and I'd like to transform this (by adding say 1.15) to

```
identifying text 2.2700
identifying text 2.2900
```

Normally I'd do this in Python, but it's on a Windows machine where I can't install too many things. I've got Vim though :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a simplification and a fix on hobbs' solution:

```
:%s/identifying text \zs\d\+\(.\d\+\)\=/\=(1.15+str2float(submatch(0)))/
```

Thanks to `\zs`, there is no need to recall the leading text. Thanks to `str2float()` a single addition is done on the whole number (in other words, 1.15 + 2.87 will give the expected result, 4.02, and not 3.102).

Of course this solution requires a recent version of Vim (7.3?)

Comment: +1. *I* can even get this to work (and that's saying a lot) but is there a way to retain the trailing zero's.

Comment: With `printf()` may be ? (:h printf()) -> `...\=printf('%.4f', 1.15+str2float(......))`

Comment: Some thing I had to look up: `\=` allows the replacement string to be an expression. ([link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_an_expression_in_substitute_command))

Comment: To add two integer numbers without a trailing decimal, use `str2nr`. For more functions, see `:h functions`

Answer (score 12):

You can do a capturing regex and then use a vimscript expression as a replacement, something like

```
:%s/\(identifying text \)\(\d\+\)\.\(\d\+\)/
  \=submatch(1) . (submatch(2) + 1) . "." . (submatch(3) + 1500)
```

(only without the linebreak).

Answer (score 3):

Your number format seems to be a fixed one, so it's easy to convert to int and come back (remove the dot) add 11500 and put the dot back.

```
:%s/\.//
:%normal11500^A " type C-V then C-a
:%s/....$/.&/
```

If you don't want to do that on all the lines but only the one which match 'identifying text' replace all the % by 'g/indentifying text/'

Answer (score 1):

For integers you can just use *n*^A to add *n* to a number (and *n*^X to subtract it). I doubt whether that works for fractional numbers though.

Answer (score 1):

Well this might not be a solution for vim but I think awk can help:

```
cat testscript | LC_ALL=C awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s %.3f\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5+1.567   }'
```

and the test

```
this is a number 1.56
this is a number 2.56
this is a number 3.56
```

I needed the LC_ALL=C for the correct conversion of the floating point separator, and maybe there is a more elegant solution for printing the beginning/ rest of the string. And the result looks like:

```
this is a number 3.127
this is a number 4.127
this is a number 5.127
```

Comment: Dam! Just read that it is a windows machine, so forget about awk :D

Answer (score 1):

Using macro

```
qa .......................... start record macro 'a'
/iden<Enter> ................ search 'ident*' press Enter
2w .......................... jump 2 words until number one  (before dot)
Ctrl-a ...................... increases the number
2w .......................... jump to number after dot
1500 Ctrl-a ................. perform increases 1500 times
q ........................... stop record to macro 'a'
```

if you have 300 lines with this pattern just now making

```
300@a
```

Comment: The OP wants to increment one number ("**a** given number" <- singular) with 1.15, and not two separate numbers.